# How to safely update Tor relay installed on VPS with Debian?

Tags: relays, debian, vps

How do I safely update a Tor relay installed on a VPS with Debian? (I don't want to lose the ID, because I'm taking part in the EFF Tor Challenge).

Answer (score 2):

If you installed it via apt you can easily update it with `apt-get upgrade`.
Your fingerprint shouldn't get lost during that process.
For safety reasons backup your private key file. It is in the following directory:

```
/var/lib/tor/keys/secret_id_key
```